# Highcharts node export datalabel not rendering html

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have the following config:

```
series: [{
    name: '',
    color: "black",
    data: [5.4, 3],
    showInLegend: false,
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return `<div style="max-width: 10ch; text-align: center;">${this.y}<br/>mmol/L</div>`;
        }
    }
}]
```

However it doesn't seem as if this "formatter" is being used as the chart looks like this:

[image]

This is only an issue when I use the node export server not when I attempt to render it in my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xerpqoah/55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with using `formatter` function in the `node-export-server`: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/122

In that case, you need to use `dataLabels.format`:

```
"format": "<div style='max-width: 10ch; text-align: center;'>{point.y}<br/>mml/L</div>"
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnqkhzxL/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.format